# accessing imdb data using Django

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to make a django application as i am currently learning tango with django(http://www.tangowithdjango.com/)..the application is based on imdb-pie client(https://github.com/pravarag/imdb-pie), which will display the data from imdb to a specific user as he/she logs in to their account..but when i tried to run the code there was no connection made to the client and nothing retrieve from the site and displayed null result.
Here's my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from imdbpie import Imdb

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from datetime import datetime


imdb = Imdb()

def index(request):
    pass



def user_login(request):

    context_dict={}

    top250=imdb.top_250()

    lst=[]

    for i in top250:
        for k, v in i.items():
            if k=="title":
                lst.append(v)

    context_dict['moviesTop250']=lst


    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/imdbApp')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Rango account is disabled")
        else:
            print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Login details supplied")
    else:
        return render(request, 'imdbApp/login.html', context_dict)


@login_required
def restricted(request):
    return HttpResponse("")


@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/imdbApp/")

def homepage(request):
    pass

def result(request):
    pass
```

and here's my login template(login.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to the ImdbApp</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/imdbApp/login">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50"/><br/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <h4><a href="/imdbApp/register/">Register new User!!</a></h4>

    <p>
        {% if moviesTop250 %}
            <ul>
                {% for i in moviesTop250 %}
                    {% for j in i %}
                        <li>{{ j }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <STRONG>Nothing here "SIRE"</STRONG>
        {% endif %}


    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

so instead of displaying the top 250 results on the login page i see "Nothing here sire" msg, which means no connection was made to the imdb-pie client..i'm running the whole django project on the virtualenv and my os is OS X 10.10..the imdb-pie client is installed in the same directory where django is installed.should i try to install it in my app directory?

Comment: Have you tried executing `imdb.top_250()` from the shell?

Comment: Yes, i created a separate python script to access the data through imdv-pie.. it's working there but when not with my django project

Comment: I just tried this...it's working for me. Interesting

Comment: is the code right?? can there be a connection problem ?

Comment: There could be. If you're running this through the django development server (runserver), you could try adding some `print()` statements to your view to see if things are actually being retrieved

Comment: thanks..i will try restart my system and everything else and add some print tests..